# Previously successful Scapy installation for Python 3, sniff() now failing with AttributeError

Tags: macos, python-3.x, scapy

On Mac OS 10.13.1
Using Scapy for the first time to do a simple packet-sniffing project.

Was working perfectly fine over the weekend after following the installation instructions here for Mac OS:
https://phaethon.github.io/scapy/api/installation.html

Hardware problems required me to move my work to a different machine, running the exact same OS.
I figured "no problem" - setup a new Python 3 venv and reinstalled dependencies on the second laptop (libdnet via brew, libpcap and scapy3k via pip).
Now a simple test using sniff() in Scapy produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "/Users/ersheff/Virtualenvs/Scapy/lib/python3.6/site->packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 576, in sniff
>
> s = L2socket(type=ETH_P_ALL, *arg, **karg)
>
> File "/Users/ersheff/Virtualenvs/Scapy/lib/python3.6/site->packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 469, in **init**
>
> self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, >socket.htons(type))
>
> AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_PACKET'

I'm well aware that the AF_PACKET attribute is not available on Mac OS and is specific to Linux, and as you might expect, all of my searching about this problem leads to that answer. However, as mentioned, this method was working for me before on a different machine with the same OS.

Admittedly, I'm a novice, but reading that error makes it look to me like Scapy is erroneously referring to the linux.py file in the arch directory when it should be referring to the bsd.py or unix.py files (both of which are present).

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old. For the record, the official scapy version now supports Python 3. OSX has been fixed on their sides:

https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Have a nice week,